# Validation for names in a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input for a name. I want to allow only letters and non-consecutive white-spaces anywhere, except that white-space isn't allowed at the start or end of the input. So I have to invalidate numbers, symbols, and consecutive white-space.

Examples:

1. `rohit_kumar_mehta`
2. `rohit__kumar_mehta`
3. `rohit_kumar__mehta`
4. `_rohit_kumar_mehta`
5. `__rohit_kumar_mehta`
6. `rohit_kumar_mehta_`

`_` -- means single white-space

`__` -- means double white-space

String 1 is right.

Strings 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are wrong.

I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.myForm.fname.value;
    var spacepos = x.indexOf(" ");
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var n = x.split("  ");
    //x.innerHTML = n[0];

    var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if ((iChars.indexOf(x.charAt(i)) != -1)) {
            alert("invalid...1");
            return false;
        }
        /**else if ((numbers.indexOf(x.numberAt(i)) != -1) && spacepos > 0) {
            alert("invalid...3");
            return false;
        }**/
    }

    var alphabets = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if ((n[0].match(alphabets) && spacepos > 0)) {
        alert("doublke space......1");
    }
    /*else if ((n[1].match(alphabets) && spacepos > 0)) {
        alert("doublke space.....2");
    }*/
    else if ((x.match(alphabets) || spacepos > 0)) {   
        alert("ok..2");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("invalid..2");
        return false;
    }

    /**if(x==" ") {
        alert("invalid..3");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("ok...3")
        return true;
    }**/
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about names that legitimately contain `'` or `-`?

Comment: try this /(\w+\s\w+)+/g

Answer (score 3):

Your function may be something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var value = document.myForm.fname.value;
    if(value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+)*$/)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Wrong name');
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function will allow to enter names that consist of one or more words without numbers and special characters, having one space between words and without starting or trailing spaces.

Example here http://jsbin.com/iducuq/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Try validateNameField() method, may this help you...

```
function validateNameField() {
    $value = $('#name').val();
    if(/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+)*$/.test($value)) {
        alert('Acceptable valid Name');
    } else {
        alert('invalid Name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze the string in a reverse manner:

```
function stripInvalidChars(input){
     var re = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;
     var match = new Array();
     match = re.exec(input);
     return match.join(' ');
}
```

This function will match only the valid characters (trimming spaces).
Then you can check the original string against this new string, if they are the same the string is valid.